# Regex to match if first 5 characters of string

Tags: regex

Hi I need a regex to match a pattern, the first 5 charcters must be exactly "54321" and the entire string must be 16 characters long and can only contain numbers

Thanx

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?  Thanx

Comment: Try this: ^54321\w{11}$

Comment: Thanx this got me on the right track, not sure what the '$' does but this seems to work best for my situation ^54321[0-9]{11}

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
(54321)\d{11}
```

54321 to exactly match 54321

and since entire string must be 16

so \d{11} to match for any number with length 11